# CloudPagesURL() function within an email and send through a journey results error 500 - Internal server error

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, journeybuilder, cloudpage

Within the email piece I'm using %%=CloudPagesURL(1085)=%% in a button, in testing, it works fine, but when I send it through a journey, and click the button, the link that generates show an error 500 - Internal server error.

There is some issue with journey builder and CloudPagesURL function?

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the resolved URL, it must be your Journey adds some analytics which breaks the URL.

Comment: Thanks, the error was because I wasn't uncheck the conversion tracking link, I tried without that and it works